# Error "operation not permitted, scandir" when run ng test on Docker

Tags: node.js, angular, docker

I try to run unit test in my proyect on a Docker container, tests run fine on my local machine but when run it on the docker countainer I have no idea what happens.

when i run the comand `npm test` this is the error in the console:

```
/app # npm test

> home-tarjetas@0.0.0 test /app
> ng test --code-coverage --no-watch

10% building modules 1/1 modules 0 active05 09 2018 20:05:30.036:INFO 
[karma]: Karma v2.0.5 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
05 09 2018 20:05:30.038:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser 
ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox with unlimited concurrency
05 09 2018 20:05:32.466:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser ChromeHeadless
Unhandled rejection Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 
'/proc/1/map_files/563394025000-5633940e6000'
at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:861:3)
at GlobSync._readdir (/app/node_modules/glob/sync.js:288:41)
at GlobSync._readdirInGlobStar (/app/node_modules/glob/sync.js:245:17)
at GlobSync._readdir (/app/node_modules/glob/sync.js:276:17)
at GlobSync._processReaddir (/app/node_modules/glob/sync.js:137:22)
at GlobSync._process (/app/node_modules/glob/sync.js:132:10)
at GlobSync._processGlobStar (/app/node_modules/glob/sync.js:380:10)
at GlobSync._process (/app/node_modules/glob/sync.js:130:10)
at GlobSync._processGlobStar (/app/node_modules/glob/sync.js:383:10)
at GlobSync._process (/app/node_modules/glob/sync.js:130:10)
at GlobSync._processGlobStar (/app/node_modules/glob/sync.js:383:10)
at GlobSync._process (/app/node_modules/glob/sync.js:130:10)
at GlobSync._processGlobStar (/app/node_modules/glob/sync.js:383:10)
at GlobSync._process (/app/node_modules/glob/sync.js:130:10)
at new GlobSync (/app/node_modules/glob/sync.js:48:10)
at new Glob (/app/node_modules/glob/glob.js:129:12)

05 09 2018 20:06:32.472:WARN [launcher]: ChromeHeadless have not captured in 
60000 ms, killing.
05 09 2018 20:06:34.477:WARN [launcher]: ChromeHeadless was not killed in 
2000 ms, sending SIGKILL.
05 09 2018 20:06:36.481:WARN [launcher]: ChromeHeadless was not killed by 
SIGKILL in 2000 ms, continuing.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

This is my **DockerFile**:

```js
FROM 172.17.200.7:5000/alpine-node-base:v1.0.0

 LABEL name="home-m"
 LABEL author="fgt"



 RUN mkdir /app

 WORKDIR /app

 COPY . .

 RUN rm -rf node_modules

 CMD ["top"]
```

**package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "home-m",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test --code-coverage --no-watch",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build:packagr": "ng-packagr -p package.json",
    "publish": "npm publish ./dist-module"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ngx-swiper-wrapper": "^6.4.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.12",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.117",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "ng-packagr": "^4.1.1",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "puppeteer": "^1.7.0",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

**karma.conf.js**

```js
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('puppeteer').executablePath();

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '..',
    files:[
      '**/*.spec.ts'
    ],
    exclude: [
    ],
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox'],
    customLaunchers:{
      ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox:{
        base:'ChromeHeadless',
        flags:['--no-sandbox','--disable-gpu']
      }
    },
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Comment: Can you share your `docker run` command?  The Dockerfile you shared, oddly, runs `top`, which doesn't seem like it will run your unit tests.

Comment: I run  the docker whit "docker run -it --rm home-m sh",  and then in to container I run : 1.- "npm i" 2.- "npm test"